# Duplicate record read to Internal Table

Tags: abap, opensql

My internal table have double record when show, ex: 10 in billing documents, but 20 in my internal table. MAKTX were display whereby a SPEC-TEST was added to the duplicate value.

```
SELECT * INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF wa_alv_list
FROM VBRK
INNER JOIN VBRP ON VBRK~VBELN = VBRP~VBELN "BILLING DOCUMENTS (HEADER)
AND VBRK~VKORG = VBRP~VKORG_AUFT
INNER JOIN MAKT ON VBRP~MATNR = MAKT~MATNR
WHERE VBRK~VKORG = VKORG
AND VBRK~BUKRS = BUKRS
AND VBRK~FKDAT IN S_FKDAT
AND VBRP~WERKS IN S_WERKS
ORDER BY VBRK~FKDAT.
```

Does the above sql caused the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are joining with `MAKT` (material texts), but there is no restriction for a language. The double quantity of entries can be explained with materials texts in two languages.

Can you give the definition of `wa_alv_list`? Or try to add `MAKT-LANGU` (or `MAKT-SPRAS`- I'm not sure which one) and a material text to check if you get an entry per language.

---

I would recommend to define a parameter:

```
PARAMETERS: P_SPRAS like SY-LANGU OBLIGATORY DEFAULT SY-LANGU.
```

Now you can select the language (e.g. with F4) when you start the report.

```
SELECT * INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF wa_alv_list
  FROM VBRK
  INNER JOIN VBRP ON VBRK~VBELN = VBRP~VBELN "BILLING DOCUMENTS (HEADER)
  AND VBRK~VKORG = VBRP~VKORG_AUFT
  INNER JOIN MAKT ON VBRP~MATNR = MAKT~MATNR
  WHERE VBRK~VKORG = VKORG
  AND VBRK~BUKRS = BUKRS
  AND VBRK~FKDAT IN S_FKDAT
  AND VBRP~WERKS IN S_WERKS
  and MAKT~SPRAS = p_SPRAS  "<---Added
  ORDER BY VBRK~FKDAT.
```

One warning: If the material has no text in the selected  language, then no entry is found.

Comment: It work! The system select a record with language 'Z'. Could you brief me on what language is that?

Comment: @RamonC Check the value table of `SPRAS`(`T002`).

Comment: Is for customer reserve, but is there anyway to do setting to default to only one language instead of apply condition for every queris?